# Why does the comment section of an elf binary contain multiple compiler comments?

Tags: gcc, clang, elf

When I compile a binary with the clang compiler shipped in my distro, then read the ELF headers of said binary with `readelf -p .comment <path>`, it shows me multiple compilers in the comment section:

```
String dump of section '.comment':
  [     0]  GCC: (GNU) 7.3.0
  [    11]  GCC: (GNU) 10.3.0
  [    23]  clang version 13.0.0
```

I expected it to show the clang version, but why are there also comments about gcc, and different versions non the less?

Answer (score 0):

> why are there also comments about gcc,

Your linked binary contains object files compiled by the 3 different compilers.

- Your own object files are compiled by `clang`.
- The object files which part of GLIBC, such as `crt0.o`, are (likely) compiled by GCC.
- You are linking in some library(ies) compiled by a different version of GCC.

You can figure out all files the linker uses by linking with `clang ... -Wl,-t` flag. Once you know all the files participating in the link, you can run `readelf -p.comment` on each one to figure out what files where compiled with a given version of the compiler.

Comment: What does " [     0]", "[    11]", "[    23]" mean in the output?

Comment: @Dollyn Given that `sizeof("GCC: (GNU) 7.3.0") == 0x11` and `sizeof("GCC: (GNU) 10.3.0") == 0x12`, I am guessing the number is a hex offset into the `.comment` section. To be sure, read the `readelf` source.